# Axiom to prove $ \sqrt2 $ is irrational by contradiction.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, real-numbers

$ \sqrt2 $ is irrational. Proof By contradiction.

Assume $ \sqrt2 $ is not irrational i.e. Assume $ \sqrt2 $ is rational.

...

...

...

Since $ \sqrt2 $ is rational is false , hence $ \sqrt2 $ must be irrational.

Isn't this assumption **$ \sqrt2 $ is rational** incomplete? Shouldn't one also prove that $ \sqrt2 $ is also not an imaginary number or one of my axioms state something like there are only either rational or irrational numbers and then proceed with this proof??

By contradiction we just prove  $ \sqrt2 $ is rational is false, but $ \sqrt2 $ can still be something that's either imaginary, complex or yet even not discovered.

Comment: What are "your axioms" ? Maybe you are working in $\mathbb R$...

Comment: No, the claim is just "proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is **not** rational." So all we have to assume is, it would be rational. Clearly $\sqrt{2}$ is also a complex number, namely $1\cdot \sqrt{2}+0\cdot i$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA so I do have to define a domain of discourse explicitly else my proof is incomplete. Am I correct?

Comment: @DietrichBurde But isn't it that I still cannot safely conclude for something that exists but may not yet be discovered?

Comment: Yes, at least the domain of *rationals*; having said that, nothing changes if you consider e.g. complex numbers: [$\sqrt 2$ will still be **not** rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_2#Proofs_of_irrationality)

Comment: What you are proving essentially, is that there is no rational number whose square is $2$, so you don't really have to worry about other domains.  In the same sense you could prove $\sqrt{-1}$ is not rational, even if complex numbers haven't been discovered.

Comment: I think we can all agree that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational. The question is: What is it? That's a different question entirely. You can prove that the polynomial $x^2-2$ has exactly two solutions (of opposite sign) over $\mathbb{R}$. The positive solution is then denoted by $\sqrt{2}$. The way you prove this depends on how you actually defined $\mathbb{R}$ and is substantially more difficult then showing that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank You so much. Clarifies my doubt. The question I am going through doesn't specifically mention the domain and neither does the solution. It just goes straight to prove the p/q cannot be in its lowest form for $ \sqrt2 $.

Comment: Since the opposite of irrational is rational, your statement that "there are only either rational or irrational numbers" is a tautology (always true), at least in standard logic (due to the "law of the excluded third"). So you do not need to assume anything else.

Comment: The underlying assumption is that there is a *real number* whose square is $2$. You aren’t trying to prove this; you are trying to prove that it is an *irrational* number. Those reals which are not rational are irrational (definition), so there is nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, we do not prove that $\sqrt 2$ even exists, i.e., we only prove

> There is no rational number $x$ with $x^2=2$.

Similarly, we can prove

> There is no rational number $x$ with $0\cdot x=1$.

But after such a proof, we would not say that "$\frac10$ is irrational".  Instead, we say that $\frac 10$ is not defined. What is the difference?

Historically, $\sqrt 2$ appeard as length of the diagonal of a unit square, which by Pythagoras had the property that $x^2=2$. So the existence in *some* sense was not under doubt. But once we are given existence of a number with this property (or with another property $P$), there is no difference between "There is no rational number with property $P$" and "The (or any) number with property $P$ is irrational". Note that all non-real complex numbers, for example are irrational, hence questions about real or imaginary or complex can be ignored. If we know, say, from the fundamental theorem of algebra that $X^2-2$ has *some* complex root, then there is no need to first show that it is real before showing that it is not rational.

Comment: Precisely, this is a clear answer that actually helps the poster. Showing that $\sqrt{2}$ exists and belongs to $\mathbb{R}$ is a different story. 

If for some reason your definition of irrational is an element of $\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ (as opposed to defining irrational as simply not rational), then the OP has a very valid point that showing that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational does not prove the statement.

Comment: @Mathematician 42 I apologize as I was not aware of the fact that complex numbers are irrationals too. In my defense its been a long time since I have done any mathematics. Thank you so much for the clarification as I was going through the MIT 6.042J fall 2010 course and the proof didn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Aura : Don't apologize! In many courses (where they don't venture outside the realm of real numbers), irrationals are defined as real numbers which are not rational. To be fair, that's a perfectly acceptable definition and your question is very valid.

Comment: @Mathematician42 That's precisely how irrational was depicted in the course. Irrational was depicted to be a decimal number with non repeating pattern of digits after the decimal. Hence, I just assumed that irrational is just a real number which is not rational. Thank you once again for letting me know that my assumption was partially (or entirely (depending on the context)) correct. :)

Answer (score 1):

If we define $\sqrt2$ to be the positive root of $x^2-2=0$, by Newton's method we may show that the sequence $$x_{n+1}=x_n-{f(x_n)\over f'(x_n)}={x_n^2+2\over 2x_n}\quad,\quad x_1=1$$tends to $\sqrt 2$. Since all the terms of this sequence are real, so must be $\sqrt 2$, since a non-zero imaginary part forces $\sqrt 2$ to lie above the real line.